# How can I programatically move users between View Controllers in Xcode?

Tags: swift, xcode, viewcontroller

Once a user logs into my application, the below function should automatically redirect the user to a View Controller named 'TabViewController'.

```
transitionToHome() {
    
    let tabViewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.Storyboard.TabViewController) as? TabViewController
    
    view.window?.rootViewController = tabViewController
    view.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    
}
```

Currently, when this function is run, it just produces a fully black screen, instead of taking the user to the TabViewController.

Here is a screenshot from Xcode of my ViewController.

[image: Xcode picture]

This is the code in my 'TabViewController.swift' file

```
import UIKit

class TabViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

}
```

And here is my declaration of the ViewController in my 'constants' file

```
import Foundation

struct Constants {

struct Storyboard {
    
    static let homeViewController = "HomeVC"
    
    static let TabViewController = "TabVC"
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in explaining why this might be happening and how to actually get it to redirect to the TabViewController, thanks!

Comment: use this for window : ```UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController = tabViewController
        UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.makeKeyAndVisible()```

Comment: What @RajaKishan said would work, but you could also create a new `TabViewController` object and pass that in as the rootViewController if you wish.

Comment: Not too sure where the above code would need to be added? Could you elaborate please Raja?

Answer (score 1):

Make the UITabViewController the Initial View Controller. Then, after the app launches, check if the user is logged in within the first view controller of your tab controller. If they aren't, programmatically present the login controller. When they login successfully, dismiss the login controller back to that first view controller.

sample code (where HomeViewController is the first view controller of the tab controller):

```
class HomeViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        if !userIsLoggedIn {
            presentLoginController()
        }
    }
    
    private var userIsLoggedIn: Bool {
        false // placeholder - need to compute this elsewhere, otherwise login controller will always present
    }
    
    private func presentLoginController() {
        guard let loginController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginVC") else {
            return
        }
        
        loginController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        
        present(loginController, animated: false)
    }
}

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBAction func loginTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        if loginCredentialsCorrect {
            dismiss(animated: true)
        }
    }
    
    private var loginCredentialsCorrect: Bool {
        true // placeholder
    }
}
```